# Unable to authenticate with salesforce standard REST API from a different web page using ajax

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, authentication, connected-apps, ajax-toolkit

I want to connect with standard REST API from a different domain using ajax call. Below is the ajax function I am using.

```
function call_API() {
        $.ajax({
            url : URL,
            type : 'POST',
            dataType :'application/json',
            data : {
                "grant_type"    : grantType,
                "client_id"     : clientID, 
                "client_secret" : clientSecret,
                "username"      : username,
                "password"      : password
            },
            beforeSend: function (request) {
              request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
              request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT");
              request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description"); 
            },
            crossDomain : true,
            success : function(result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error : function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            } 
        });
    }
```

When I call the ajax function I got the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&clie…=7003112788871309690&username=myUserName&password=PASSWORD. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://360degreecloud.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

Anyone has an idea to deal with this?

Comment: It's too late but did you find any solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue. You have to whitelist `https://360degreecloud.com` domain in Salesforce CORS setting (Setup | Security Controls | CORS).

Please follow this link for more details - https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/01/spring-15-preview-cors-force-com-rest-api.html

Comment: I have already added my domain in CORS.